# Is there a better way to read ACLs in Ruby than parsing ls output?

Tags: ruby, macos, permissions

On Mac OS X, [`ls`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) and [`chmod`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html) have some extra features for handling the [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) permissions that the OS layers on top of the default posix permissions. I [have some permission problems that need fixing](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2686643), and I [wrote a script](https://gist.github.com/882414) to help patch up these problems until Apple fix that bug. Here's the code that parses [`ls`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) to get the the [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list):

```
result = `#{Escape.shell_command(["ls", "-led", file])}`
if result.empty?
    # ls error...
else
    @acl = result.split("\n")[1..-1].collect do |ace|
        ace = ace.split(": ", 2)
        ace[0] = ace[0].to_i
        ace
    end
    # acl processing code...
end
```

I added the [escape](http://rubygems.org/gems/escape) gem, but it's still virtually the same code.

But I know it's a bad idea in general to parse [`ls`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) in a script, so is there a better way to read the [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) permissions from a file?

I need the ACEs and their indices to use with [`chmod`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html) later on in the script:

```
system("chmod -a# #{index} \"#{file}\"")
```

Comment: `ls -led` gets the OS X advanced attributes, correct?  I don't think Ruby will have built-in support for these attributes.  @Swanand: the mode only deals with the normal unix permission bits doesn't it?

Comment: @Nemo157 Yes, sorry I forgot, the `-e` option is probably unique to OS X. It prints out the ACLs after the standard `-l` output

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking through the Ruby 1.8.7 [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/File.html#M000858)  class. If my one-minute reading is correct, what I gather is that the permissions of the process will govern what you can see from the file, which is exactly what `ls` will do.

So, if the Ruby script is running as root, it can get all kinds of info about a file, but if it is running as a user, and that user is not in the file's group, and the file is not world-readable for example, then the script cannot see that file.

It seems like if you are running a script as a certain user, and you want to change a file's permissions, you can gather them up and change them with Ruby 1.8.7's `chmod` in the above link, no?

Comment: Mac OS X's chmod has ACL management bundled into it. I remember reading somewhere that this is not the standard Unix way of dealing with ACLs (correct me if I'm wrong). Does Ruby's chmod take account for this or does it just do the standard Unix chmod behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for IRB. (Type `irb` at the command line). If you don't already, you should consider using IRB if you're writing Ruby, and/or `rails console` if you're writing a Ruby on Rails application. When you launch the latter at the root of a Rails application, you will load IRB with all (or most) of the code associated with your Rails app.

I made two files, "file_1.txt" and "file_2.txt". As user "charlie", I open up an IRB shell from the directory where these files are located, and played around with Ruby's File class on those two files:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root     staff  30 Mar 22 09:06 file_1.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 charlie  staff  16 Mar 22 09:06 file_2.txt

charlie:stackoverflow charlie$ man ls
charlie:stackoverflow charlie$ irb
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :001 > File.writable?("file_1.txt")
=> false
```

Then, I did the same as root:

```
irb(main):002:0> File.writable?("file_1.txt")
=> true
irb(main):003:0> File.writable?("file_2.txt")
=> true
irb(main):004:0>
```

That's my modus operandi, to learn what I need to do, and I hope that helps answer your question.

Comment: Yes I have used irb, it's been very handy. But I don't know how to find a way to read the underlying ACL entries on the file from within Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
File.chmod(0644, path)              # Sets the file to 0644
printf("%o", File.stat(path).mode)  # Returns the mode as an 
                                    # integer and is converted to octal
100644 => nil
```

Comment: Sorry, that's posix permissions. I need to edit ACL permissions. So far it looks like only the system's `chmod` can handle them. I was hoping there would be some Ruby libraries for handling ACLs, so I could avoid parsing `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

how about `lstat`?

```
>> File.lstat('file')
=> #<File::Stat dev=0x803, ino=3365, mode=0100644, nlink=1, uid=0, gid=0, rdev=0x0, size=1328, blksize=4096, blocks=8, atime=2011-03-30 08:39:30 +0800, mtime=2011-03-30 08:36:34 +0800, ctime=2011-03-30 08:36:34 +0800>
>> print "%o" % ( File.lstat('file').mode & 0777  )
644
```

The above means the file called "file" has permission of 644.

Comment: I need access to ACL permissions, not the posix permissions. I've recently revised the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there isn't really a better option.  ACLs don't seem to be exposed to OSA by the Finder or System Events, so appscript won't help.  You could use FFI and the POSIX ACL functions, but the API at that level is exceedingly annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [gem](https://github.com/kcrawford/osx-acl) to do ACL reading and modifications:

```
>> require 'acl'
=> true
>> acl = OSX::ACL.of("tmp")
=> #<OSX::ACL:0x007f92eaabc578 @path="tmp">
>> acl.entries
=> [#<OSX::ACL::Entry:0x007f92eaaf7510 @components=["user", "FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000046", "_www", "70", "allow", "read"]>]
>> ace = acl.entries.first
=> #<OSX::ACL::Entry:0x007f92eaaf7510 @components=["user", "FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000046", "_www", "70", "allow", "read"]>
>> ace.assignment
=> #<OSX::ACL::Assignment:0x007f92ea2a0060 @type="user", @uuid="FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000046", @name="_www", @id="70">
>> ace.assignment.type
=> "user"
>> ace.assignment.name
=> "_www"
>> ace.rules
=> ["allow"]
>> ace.permissions
=> ["read"]
>> acl.remove_entry_at_index(0)
chmod -a# 0 tmp # user:FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000046:_www:70:allow:read
=> true
```